# Programatically calling resignFirstResponder on a UITextField without a storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` with a `UITextField`, which has variable in the custom class. I'm not using a storyboard so I don't have an outlet; I'm doing this programmatically.

I'm using `textFieldDidEndEditing` in my `UIViewController` to acquire the value a user provides.

```
    public func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
    {
        print("textvalue=\(textField.text!)")
    }
```

However, if a navigation bar button is tapped `textFieldDidEndEditing` is not called. I know normally if I had an outlet and a textfield variable on my UIViewController I could use `resignFirstResponder` which would probably cause `textFieldDidEndEditing` to be called, but as I say I'm not using an outlet / storyboard.

I don't have have this variable on my `UIViewController` for the textfield so I don't have anything to call `resignFirstResponder` on.

I guess I could call `resignFirstResponder` in my custom `UITableViewCell` but I don't have access to my my model.

Comment: Is textFieldDidEndEditing method getting called when user presses enter from the keyboard? And by navigation bar button do you mean back button?

Comment: Yes, it does get called when switching between texrfields in different rows, but not from the a button on the navigation bar,

Comment: You can access your custom `UITableViewCell` for a particular row perhaps in `DidSelectRow` and call `resignFirstResponder` from there?

Comment: Thank, wouldn’t that dismiss the keypad after every key press ?

Comment: Yes, maybe you could instead save the indexpath of the cell in a variable, and then if the user presses a tab button call resignFirstResponder on that: `let cell:CustomCell? = tableView.cellForRow(at: CustomPath) as? CustomCell
               cell?.textInput.resignFirstResponder()` so that if a button is pressed, it resigns the last tapped cell. Is that making sense?

Comment: How do you create the text field? You just store the reference in a property. `@IBOutlet` is just a flag that lets Interface Builder identify properties that are exposed to it.  There is nothing magic about the property itself.

Comment: @Peter Ruppert I have also mentioned this solution in my answer with getting delegate access while creating tableview cell and it will work

Comment: I’m not using interface builder, I’m doing everything programmatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be possible by either identify your text field using identifier such as `tags` and `accessibility` from `UITableViewDelegate` then use can use,

Set the `delegate` when create cell in

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    cell.txtField.delegate = self

  }

  // then it will be called UITextFieldDelegate

  public func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
  {

  }
```

Or you can use as per hierarchy of `subviews`:

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

Comment: Hmmm, do you mean I call `self.view.endEditing(false)` upon my button tap?

Comment: if you call `self.view.endEditing(true)` on the button tap it would dismiss any keyboards so I expect it would call didEndEditing on whichever input was being used.

Comment: @Jules Yes It is way if you dismiss process  on view like resign keyboard but depends on  hierarchy of subviews.